# How to get collection by left join that is fetched by sub select via Spring data(JPQL)?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Is it possible to get collection via sub-select and set it into the entity? I need to find entities by restriction and after that, I need to join them into another entity.

For example, I need to find company with employees that worked in company for given date

From pure SQL I need something like that:

```
 select * from Company c 
   LEFT JOIN (
    select * from Employee where  hireDate > 10.5.2015 AND departureDate < 10.12.2015
 ) e 
 on c.id = e.companyId
```

I tried it via this query in Spring data but it doesn't work

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Company c LEFT JOIN FETCH (c.employees e where e.hireDate > ?1 AND e.departureDate < ?1)) WHERE c.id = ?2)
List<Company> findCompanyWitEmployes(Long salary, Long companyId);
```

**Entities:**

```
 public class Employee{

      Long id

      String name; 

      Date hireDate;
      Date departureDate;

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "companyId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
      Company company;
    }


    public class Company{

      Long id

      String name; 

      @OneToMany(mappedBy="company", cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Set<Employee> employees;
    }
```

**I'm getting this error:**

```
2016-06-29 11:50:35.824 [ServerService Thread Pool -- 134] ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - line 1:81: expecting IDENT, found '('
2016-06-29 11:50:35.824 [ServerService Thread Pool -- 134] ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - line 1:81: expecting IDENT, found '('
antlr.MismatchedTokenException: expecting IDENT, found '('
    at antlr.Parser.match(Parser.java:211) ~[antlr-2.7.7.jar:na]
```

Comment: Spring Data has nothing to do with it. Suggest that you search for JPQL on the web. You cannot "JOIN" to a subquery, only along relations ... start with "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.employees e" without its "where" clause.

Comment: Hi, thanks for explanation.. so I have only one way how to do it, when I set lazy fetch I can get result in the next step when I  get only employees for given criterias and set them into collection from company

Comment: I've no idea what you mean. I said START with the LEFT JOIN FETCH syntax. If you want to add extra conditions on you can specify an ON clause on the JOIN ... as per any JPA 2.1 reference doc would say

Answer (score 0):

As for as I can see you forgot to put " before the right parenthesis. That is why you are getting that error.

> @Query("SELECT c FROM Company c LEFT JOIN FETCH (c.employees e where
>   e.hireDate > ?1 AND e.departureDate < ?1)) WHERE c.id = ?2 ")

Comment: No, he's getting that error because you cannot join to a subquery in JPQL